# How do I properly use .NET Core 5.x and Blazor to allow a user to perform a search, then display results efficiently, appropriately, and Blazor-like?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, .net-5

I am VERY new at C#, .NET Core, and Blazor and I am trying to get a site to work while "properly" utilizing Blazor's functionality.

How I need this to work is like this:

1. User navigates to the site: 192.168.1.100
2. Enters a query into an input field
3. My code contacts a Swagger-powered API to retrieve the data
4. A "new" page is generated with the user's requested data

Simple, yes ... and I have done it hundreds of times with standard HTML, PHP, JavaScript, Java, but never with Blazor.

I have a section at the top of the site that I want to remain "static" no matter what page the user goes to. Like this:

**User Starts Here**

[image: Main Search Page]

---

**Results Displayed Here**

[image: Search Results Page]

---

My `_Hosts.cshtml` page calls `MainLayout.razor`, which is structured like this:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<div>
    <div>
        <TopBanners />
    </div>
    <div>
        <QuickStatusIndicators />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            @Body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`@Body` loads `Index.razor` which is structured like this:

```
@page "/"
<div class="text-center">
    <HeaderLarge />
    <form method="POST" action="#">
        <DefaultSearch />
        <SearchOptions />
    </form>
</div>

@code {

}
```

And, `DefaultSearch.razor` looks like this:

```
<div id="mainSearchContainer">
    <div id="mainSearchFormContainer">
        <input id="mainSearchInputField" name="queryString" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>

@code {

}
```

I have been doing research on how to hit an API endpoint with a POST request in Blazor, and the example I have doesn't seem to use a "normal" form. This works well, and generally, looks like this:

```
@page "/search"
...
@inject IHttpClientFactory clientFactory
<h3>Search</h3>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="queryString" name="queryString" @bind="queryString" />
    <button @onclick="GetSearchResults">Get It</button>
</div>
<div id="search_response_area">
    @if (fetchedResults != null)
    {
        @foreach (var result in fetchedResults.documents)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
</div>

@code {
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://192.168.1.234:8080");
        string searchstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(search);
        StringContent content = new StringContent(searchstr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(("/api/...", content);
        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        if (httpResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            string response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            fetchedResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResultSet>(response);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

---

So, my question is this. Do I go the `<FORM>` route **OR** stick with the way I have found that works successfully using a method like this:

```
@page "/"
...
@inject IHttpClientFactory clientFactory
<div class="text-center">
    <HeaderLarge />
        @if (fetchedResults == null)
        {
            <DefaultSearch />
            <SearchOptions />
        } else {
            <SearchResultsPage />
        }
</div>

@code {
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://192.168.1.234:8080");
        string searchstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(search);
        StringContent content = new StringContent(searchstr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(("/api/...", content);
        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        if (httpResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            string response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            fetchedResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResultSet>(response);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And have the new `SearchResultsPage.razor` contain the `@foreach (var result in fetchedResults.documents)` code?

If I continue on with the `<FORM>`, how do I go about proceeding?

Comment: I think you should think again how to use http client. Once you inject IHttpClientFactory in your above code, probably, you have already registered HttpClient in DI so you should create a client via injected IHttpClientFactory ( var client = clientFactory.CreateClient() ) instead of creating new instance every time for a couple of reasons. Take a look here how to use properly IHttpClientFactory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to get back JSON serialized data, so you can deserialize it to an object for presentation.  I don't see any particular benefit in trying to package and process a form post, like you might in a normal (read: not Blazor) page.

I think you're on the right track with the latter example. It feels much more "Blazor-y" to me.

Comment: I am successfully getting JSON back in a little test app, but I don't want to build a Golden Gate Bridge to cross a creek. I tried the later example, but the `<SearchResultsPage />`  being in a different document, it does not have access to `fetchedResults` of the `Index.razor` from which I make the API call. It's very frustrating.

Comment: Blazor kind of breaks the idea of navigable pages imo.  I'd have a <SearchResults> component wherever I wanted to show results, and pass the unpacked JSON class as a Parameter.  So, basically, the last thing you showed in your previous post, Except it would be: "<SearchResults ResultSet="@MyUnpackedClass" />

Answer (score 0):

@Brian,
like in your latter code snippet, something like this perhaps:

```
@page "/search"
    @inject HttpClient Http
    
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="queryString" name="queryString" @bind="queryString" />
        <button @onclick="GetSearchResults">Get It</button>
    </div>

   <div id="search_response_area">
    @if (fetchedResults != null)
    {
        @foreach (var result in fetchedResults.documents)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
    </div>

    @code {
        private FetchedResultsModel fetchedResults = null;
        private async Task GetSearchResults()
        {
            ...
            fetchedResults = await Http.GetJsonAsync<FetchedResultsModel>(<...url to get search results...>);
        }
    }
```

In addition to your existing code, I'd suggest "separating" UI and "serverside", i.e

- you have your search.razor page - serves as UI with input fields and search results,
- your search.razor page "inherits" via @inherits SearchBase statement,
- where SearchBase is something like

  public class SearchBase:ComponentBase
  {

  ```
     [Inject] HttpClient Http { get; set; }

     [Inject] IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

     ....
     ....
  ```

  }

Comment: Thank you for the input, but my goal is to have the page "change" from the search page to the results page. I would like to replace the search area - which is the grey shaded `FORM` area in the image above - with the results area - which is the grey shaded `DATA` are in the image above - after the user clicks the "search" button. Your solution seems to be keeping both areas (form and data) on the page at the same time.

Comment: I think blazor framework is oriented towards SPA...

Comment: Correct ... which is why I am trying to hide the `DATA` area when search criteria are being entered. Then, when the results come back  from the API, hide the `FORM` area and show the `DATA` area.

Comment: oh, for that you can simply have one or two variables, so when search results are retrieved, you would (for example) change div(s) visibility <div style="@(searchresultsclassname==null?"display:none":"") " >.....</div>